# Check what part of JavaScript code is rendering a specific Html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools, screen-scraping

On this page https://detail.1688.com/offer/548835845261.html

I want to scrape shipping price and shipping weight as highlighted in image.
[image]

I dont know how is this being loaded into DOM.

Its not included in DOM. Its not even loaded by an AJAX call.

Not sure whats going on.

The only relevent part I see on initial page source is

```
data-unit-config="{"calculationUrl":"https://laputa.1688.com/offer/ajax/CalculateFreight.do","freightTemplateId":"10342228","beginAmount":"1","unitWeight":"1","refPrice":"88.00","isCodOffer":""}"
```

I tried making GET request to that URL

```
https://laputa.1688.com/offer/ajax/CalculateFreight.do?freightTemplateId=10342228&beginAmount=1&unitWeight=1&refPrice&88.00&isCodOffer
```

but not luck.

I want to ask is there any way I can check what part of JavaScript code is rendering a specific Html element?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be:

1. When the element appears, inspect it.
2. In the `Elements` panel, find the first ancestor element to the mystery element that has no mysterious origins (an element that you know how it is getting on the page).
3. Right-click the ancestor element from step #2 and navigate and select `Break on... ==> Subtree modification`
4. Refresh the page _with the devtools on the `Elements` panel (seems to not work otherwise)
5. Now anytime JavaScript modifies descendants of the element you set the breakpoint on, the sources panel will pause and allow you to inspect what is going on.